# ASPNET MVC - Route all URL subfolders to a single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am porting a website to MVC5 and need to make sure the URL structure is the same. The old site has the following URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/collections/products
https://www.example.com/products/product1-name
https://www.example.com/products/product2-name
```

I have a ProductsController for the first URL and this works great:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Products",
            url: "collections/products/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", 
                            action = "Index",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

However, I haven't found a way to map all URL requests (e.g. /products/product1-name, /products/product2-name) to a single controller. I looked at catch-all, but haven't had any success.

I could create separate controllers for product1-name, product2-name, etc. but there are thousands of products. Essentially, product1-name, product2-name are the product IDs which will are returned from the database.

Comment: Figured it out by adding another parameter:

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductItem",
    url: "products/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ProductItem", name = UrlParameter.Optional, action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Products",
            url: "collections/products/{action}/{productName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", 
                            action = "GetProductionByName",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

your will be look like **collections/products/GetProductionByName/productname** just place or write the product name and make query to find the product by name then show the column which you want to display in the view.